# jQuery - Apply Class to Image If SRC Contains String

Tags: jquery, css

I have a load of content such as

```
<div id="justThisDIV"><p>Some paragraph <img src="http://mydomain.com/image.jpg"/> </p>
<p><img src="http://mydomain.com/wow.png"/></p>
<p><img src="http://notmydomain.com/blah.png"/> Wow this is boring</p></div>
```

How can I add a class to all images that are on my domain i.e. have the URL mydomain.com contained within the DIV with ID justThisDIV

I have tried the below but no go

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div#justThisDIV img[src*=mydomain.com]").addClass("full-width");

    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: `$('#justThisDIV img[src*="mydomain.com"]')`

Comment: @pee2pee: Notice how the `src` in mine is in quotes.

Comment: `[src*="mydomain.com"]` matches `notmydomain.com`. Hopefully that's just a coincidence here.

Comment: @JasonP: N... No it doesn't!.... It does.

Answer (score 3):

**ANSWER EDITED AGAIN**

You need to add the **['attribute contains' selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)** and then use the `.parent().attr('id')` with a conditional expression to add it to the div you really want to add it to.

```
$("img[src*='imgur']").each(function () {
    if($(this).parent().attr('id')  == "thisDiv") { $(this).addClass('mine')}
});
```

or , if you want to add the class to the container, just change the reference:

```
$("img[src*='imgur']").each(function () {
    if($(this).parent().attr('id')  == "thisDiv") { $(this).parent().addClass('mine')}
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6byXw/3/)** - Add a class to the image
**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6byXw/5/)** - Add a class to the image's container

Comment: Wasn't the goal to add a class to all images? The code above will add the class to the parent elements instead.

Comment: Not really, but my answer wasn't 100% correct either, this fiddle solves it  exactly as the OP wants -> http://jsfiddle.net/6byXw/3/

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev If you compare something always use `===` in javascript.

Comment: @lesssugar `img[src*='imgur']` is matching already all images which src contains `imgur`

Comment: Thanks, I sometimes tend to forget how important strict comparison is

Answer (score 1):

The below is precisely what you need

```
$('img')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.src.match(/^http:\/\/mydomain.com/);
    })
   .addClass("full-width");
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/4YXDS/

Comment: Unless the url starts with `www`, contains `http://www` or changes to `https` in the future;) Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something with attribute starting with.
**Example:**

```
$( "img[src^='mydomain.com']" ).addClass('myClassName');
```

More informations: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: This won't work for `http://mydomain.com/....` because of `http` at the beginning. Use `*` instead of `^`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't trigger functions on DOM elements that might not be there. Check if they exist, and take then action.

```
var $img = $('img[src*="mydomain.com"]');

// Check if at least one image you need exists
if ($img.length) {
    $img.each(function() {
        // Add custom class to each img tag
        $(this).addClass('my_class');
    });
}
```

It's true that you could add the class only by typing:

```
$('img[src*="mydomain.com"]').addClass('my_class');
```

However, I think it's good to:

1. check if the elements exit
2. keep the code transparent
3. keep the code easily extendable in case you need to do different operations on the images in the future